# Issues with SQL parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to set employees for a company to 'present' if they clock-in/out on the program. The database has a field with the same name and uses a boolean value to store whether someone is or isn't present. I believe my SQL statement is correct. The issue that I continue to get is: "Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters."

Here is the code that I am using to perform the UPDATE query:

```
Private Sub btnClockout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClockout.Click
    'SelectedEmployee = lstClockin.FocusedItem.Text
    'lblClockinStatusColor.BackColor = Color.Red
    'btnClockout.Enabled = False
    'btnClockin.Enabled = True
    'lblClockinStatus.Text = "Employee is: Clocked Out"
    'If txtInfoEmployeeID.Text = "" Then
    '    MsgBox("You need to select a employee to clock-out.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    'End If

    con.ConnectionString = provider & datafile
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = ("UPDATE [EmployeeAccounts] SET [Present] = False WHERE [EmployeeID] = '" & SelectedEmployee & "'")
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "ClockOutButton")
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not a VB expert so I won't attempt an answer.  But you should realize that your current query is prone to SQL injection.  Instead, you should use a parametrized query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen +1, try looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845283/vb-net-sql-parameters-update?rq=1) for parametrized queries.

Comment: Also, are you sure you should update using a new OldDbDataAdapter ?

Comment: On top of what @Sandeep Kumar said, I would like to point out that variable SelectedEmployee is not initialised. In your example above it is commented out.

Comment: I only commented it out as it is mentioned as a public variable and that is being used for different piece of code :)

Comment: Doesn't a DataAdapter.Fill require an SQL SELECT statement it can use to fill the datatable/dataset? Did you intend to ExecuteNonQuery and then fill the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any Boolean type in SQL database. You can use below code.

```
  Private Sub btnClockout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClockout.Click
    SelectedEmployee = lstClockin.FocusedItem.Text
    'lblClockinStatusColor.BackColor = Color.Red
    'btnClockout.Enabled = False
    'btnClockin.Enabled = True
    'lblClockinStatus.Text = "Employee is: Clocked Out"
    'If txtInfoEmployeeID.Text = "" Then
    '    MsgBox("You need to select a employee to clock-out.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    'End If

    con.ConnectionString = provider & datafile
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = ("UPDATE [EmployeeAccounts] SET [Present] = 'False' WHERE [EmployeeID] = '" & SelectedEmployee & "'")
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "ClockOutButton")
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the SQL data type 'bit' to represent a Boolean value, as it can only be Null, 0 or 1. (0 = False, 1 = True)

Comment: Can we use in update statement  set  [Present] = False?

Comment: This didn't work either, the database in which it is linked too has no issue as the program works fine when it is selecting all members, just not when setting Present to true/ false for the selected employee.